# Error in installing restify using npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am trying to install restify but I am getting this error.

```
c:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install --save restify

 module.js:471

 throw err;



Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a restify problem. Check your environment variables if they're pointing to your valid local NodeJS bin-directory. Thats the place where your "npm-cli.js" should be.

How to set environment variables on different operating systems:
OSX:
[Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)
Windows:
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm
Linux:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/